# ASP.NET MVC + REST SDK + Atom Feeds + Outlook 2007 formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, outlook, syndication

I used the ASP.NET MVC REST SDK for building atom feedS for our exception logging dashboard and it worked perfect.

When creating the syndication content, I used **CreateHTMLContent** and added a PRE tag around my HTML content string. Now it shows in a nice formatted way on internet explorer. But when reading the feed through outlook 2007, I am losing the formatting totally. Do you have any idea how to format the feeds for outlook 2007.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start by going [here](http://makeofficebetter.com/Office) and vote for what is currently the number one requested fix in Outlook!

Comment: I like your answer. I just voted. :). 
But is there any work around until then?

Comment: Sorry, not that I am aware of.